# Programmatically Allow Access to IE7/IE8 clipboard

Tags: winapi, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, clipboard

Is there a way to programmatically disable the "Allow Access" message box that keeps getting in the way of the user every time my program tries to read IE's clipboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: .NET Framework 3.0 has an API for that: [IInternetSecurityManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537130%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained where your program is running specifically. The client user may use Tools > Internet Options > Security > Custom... to adjust the security option. If you're hosting the web browser control, you can use the Feature Control Key to opt-out of clipboard protections.

Comment: (1) what do you mean by "where your program is running"? OS version? (2) I am not hosting the web browser control, I am just accessing IHTMLDocument2 provided by IE. (3) Is there a way to programmatically adjust the options at "Tools > Internet Options > Security > Custom..."? Thanks.